# SQL ERROR : "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I'm getting an error when I try to create the table 'Dossier_Financement':

```
create table Dossier_Financement 
(
    ID_Reunion integer foreign key references Reunion(ID_Reunion),
    ID_Dossier integer foreign key references Dossier(ID_Dossier),
    Decision varchar(20),
    Motif text,
    Montant_Retenu decimal(6,2),/* montant accorder */
    Duree_Retenu smallint,/*nb jours accorder */
    Nom_Giac varchar(50) foreign key references GIAC(Nom_Giac),
    primary key(ID_Dossier,Nom_Giac,ID_Reunion)
)
GO
```

These are the two tables:

```
create table Reunion 
(
    ID_Reunion integer ,
    Date_Reunion datetime,
    ID_Membre integer,/*jquery*/
    Type_Reunion varchar(20),
    Nom_Giac varchar(50),
    foreign key(ID_Membre,Nom_Giac) references Membre(ID_Membre,Nom_Giac),
    primary key(ID_Reunion,Nom_Giac)
)
GO


create table Dossier_Financement 
(
    ID_Reunion integer foreign key references Reunion(ID_Reunion),
    ID_Dossier integer foreign key references Dossier(ID_Dossier),
    Decision varchar(20),
    Motif text,
    Montant_Retenu decimal(6,2),/* montant accorder */
    Duree_Retenu smallint,/*nb jours accorder */
    Nom_Giac varchar(50) foreign key references GIAC(Nom_Giac),
    primary key(ID_Dossier,Nom_Giac,ID_Reunion)
)
GO
```

The 'Reunion' execute normally without any problem but I get this error when trying to create the second table:

```
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Reunion' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Dossier_F__ID_Re__5629CD9C'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Comment: Is what it says. The column(s) in the "Master Table" must be a Key. Reunion.ID_Reunion fails this requirement if it's not *paired* with Now_Giac.

Comment: ID_Reunion in Reunion table must be primary key.

Comment: but it does have a primary key Reunion(ID_Reunion)

Comment: @Yassineedouiri It has a compound PK (ID_Reunion, Now_Giac). This does not imply that ID_Reunion (without Now_Giac) is a Key.

Comment: create table Reunion 
(
    ID_Reunion integer ,
    primary key(ID_Reunion,Nom_Giac)
)
GO

Comment: @Yassineedouiri See above. That creates a **compound** PK. ID_Reunion, *by itself*, is not a PK (or a candidate key). That says that ID_Reunion **and** Non_Giac, *when used together*, uniquely identify a row. This does not mean that ID_Reunion *when used by itself* uniquely identifiers a row. However, ID_Reunion is *used by itself* in the FK relationship, which is not allowed. A [Candidate] Key is uniquely identifiers a row. (All PKs are CKs). It is likely that ID_Reunion should be the PK and there should be a CK or, a unique index on (ID_Reuinion, Nom_Giac).

Comment: Oops, actually there is no point to create a unique index on (ID_Reuinion, Nom_Giac) as there is no way ID_Reuinion can be duplicated if it is a Key itself. An index might be useful, or perhaps it should just be entirely removed.

Comment: tnks dudde for your help ... can you be more specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There are no Primary or Candidate Keys in the referenced table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213301/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending upon the actual model needs/requirements, one solution is to reference the Key, which requires *all* parts (note that `Nom_Giac` is added to the FK definition):

```
create table Dossier_Financement 
(
    ...
    foreign key(ID_Reunion,Nom_Giac) references Reunion(ID_Reunion,Nom_Giac),
)
```

---

Another solution, as per Mark M's answer is to make the ID_Reunion column a Key (note that `Nom_Giac` is removed from the PK definition):

```
create table Reunion 
(
    ...
    primary key(ID_Reunion)
)
```

This will make ID_Reunion a Key (the Primary Key, in fact) which can then be referenced with `foreign key references Reunion(ID_Reunion)`.

Happy coding!

Comment: Also, if trying the first option, the columns need to be listed in the order they appear in the key.  (The example is correct, but it bears mentioning)

Answer (score 3):

You can only make a foreign key using the complete primary key of the table you are referencing.  Your 2nd table tries to create a foreign key using only half of the Reunion table's primary key.

Comment: It doesn't have to be *the* Primary Key; a Unique Index (which implies it is a Candidate Key) would also suffice.

Comment: However, I believe that it likely *should* be the PK, so +1.

Comment: tnks dudde for your help  ... can you be more specific

Comment: Your primary key on Reunion is declared as `ID_Reunion,Nom_Giac`, but your foreign key reference from Dossier_Financement only uses `ID_Reunion`.  It needs to use both columns you declared as the primary key, or you need to change the Reunion primary key to only include `ID_Reunion`.

Comment: @pst: Theoretically you are correct, but in practice many RDBMS systems require that the foreign key references a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Create unique index on column you that you want to create index on:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UX_Index] ON dbo.[Table]([Column1],[Column2])
```