# There are no Primary or Candidate Keys in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

> Error: There are no Primary or Candidate Keys in the referenced table
>   'dbo.Customers' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key 'FK_Reservation_Customers_FrstNme FOREIGN KEY'

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Customers;
DROP TABLE dbo.Staff;
DROP TABLE dbo.Rooms;
DROP TABLE dbo.Reservation;
GO
CREATE TABLE "Customers"(

    CustomerID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(20) NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(20) NULL,
    StreetNo int NULL,
    City nvarchar(20) NULL,
    PostCode nvarchar(20) NULL,
    Email nvarchar(50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY
    (
        CustomerID
    )
)
CREATE TABLE "Staff"(

    StaffID nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Pass nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Staff PRIMARY KEY
    (
        StaffID
    )
)
CREATE TABLE "Rooms"(

    RoomNo int NOT NULL,
    RoomType nvarchar(20) NULL,
    PricePerNight money NULL,
    MaximumOccupancy int NULL,
    No0fBeds int NULL,
    NoOfBathrooms int NULL,
    Entertainment bit NULL,
    RoomService bit NULL,
    Gym bit NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Rooms PRIMARY KEY
    (
        RoomNo
    )
)
CREATE TABLE "Reservation"(

    ReservationID int IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID int NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(20) NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(20) NULL,
    RoomType nvarchar(20) NULL,
    RoomNo int NOT NULL,
    CheckInDate date NULL,
    CheckOutDate date NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Reservation PRIMARY KEY
    (
        ReservationID
    ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Reservation_Customers_CustID FOREIGN KEY
    (
        CustomerID
    )   
        REFERENCES dbo.Customers
        (
            CustomerID
        ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Reservation_Customers_FrstNme FOREIGN KEY
    (
        FirstName
    )
        REFERENCES dbo.Customers
        (
            FirstName
        )
    )
```

Could someone please tell me whats happening here and how i can fix it. Same problem occurs with all the other keys i want to make a foreign key. Except if i want to reference a primary key.

Comment: You try to add a foreign key mapped to a field which is nullable, not unique...

And by the way, you try to add two foreign keys referencing the same table. What you want to achieve with this second key ?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you want to create a foreign key, it must reference either the primary key, or a field with a unique constraint.

If you want to display the customer's name, make the foreign key reference the CustomerID, and display the results with a join.

Comment: Thank you i understand now. - This would also mean i wouldint need firstname and lastname in Reservation, if im going to use a join to display the firstname and lastname from the customer table correct?!

Comment: That's right. Unless you're concerned with knowing the customer's name at the time of the reservation, irrespective of any subsequent changes they may make to their name

Comment: By adding `UNIQUE` to my column that I'm trying to reference, the error went away:
`guid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL UNIQUE`

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this error when specifying key columns in the referenced table that were out of the same order that the primary key or candidate key was defined with on the reference table.

Switching the order the columns were specified fixed it.

Ex:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MCL_item_vendor_override_mst]  WITH CHECK ADD  
CONSTRAINT [FK_MCL_item_vendor_override_mst_item_mst] FOREIGN KEY([item],[site_ref])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[item_mst] ([item],[site_ref])
```

failed while

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MCL_item_vendor_override_mst]  WITH CHECK ADD  
CONSTRAINT [FK_MCL_item_vendor_override_mst_item_mst] FOREIGN KEY([site_ref],[item])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[item_mst] ([site_ref],[item])
```

worked.

Comment: Hi, Can we use any one of the column as a foreign key references? if yes means, how can we use it

Comment: This was the problem for me too, the order of the specified columns.