# Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.

Tags: sql-server

below is my code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_company] (
    [Id]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [company_Id]    INT           NOT NULL,
    [typeOfCompany] VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [ownership_Id]  INT           NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_company] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

i am getting below error:
The referenced table '[dbo].[tbl_company]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213301/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are not having any foreign keys. Can you check whether you have pasted the exact query that you were running?

There are no errors in this query. When I ran it in my database, it ran without any errors.

Comment: I know. But, I don't have enough reputation to post a comment. So, posted as an answer.

Comment: Don't do so. Provide some useful answer and earn reputation, then you post comment...