# SQL Server : there are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK'

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, ddl

I've been trying to solve this error for several minutes but I don't know what am I missing from table definition.

The code for the tables are below:

Table `Autocare`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Autocare] 
(
     [IDAutocar]    NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL,
     [IDTipAutocar] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDAutocar] ASC, [IDTipAutocar] ASC),

     CONSTRAINT [FK_Autogari_TipAutocar] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDTipAutocar]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[TipAutocar] ([IDTipAutocar])
);
```

Table `Curse`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Curse]
(
    [IDCursa] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [IDTraseu] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [Data] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    [IDCompanie] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [NrLocuri] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [IDAutocar] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Trasee] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([IDTraseu]) 
       REFERENCES [Trasee]([IDTraseu]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Companii] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([IDCompanie]) 
       REFERENCES [Companii]([IDCompanie]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Autocare] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([IDAutocar]) 
       REFERENCES [Autocare]([IDAutocar])
)
```

When I try to execute the second script I get the following error (and I know is something related to the relationship between tables) and I don't figure out where the problem might be. I'm a newbie into C# and SQL Server, so please forgive if I asked a stupid question.

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Autocare' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Curse_Autocare'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: You have composite PK in first table of two columns and creating FK only on one column. This is the problem. You should add IdTipAutocar column in second table and make FK on both this and IDAutocar columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879735/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table-that-match-the-re)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There are no Primary or Candidate Keys in the referenced table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213301/there-are-no-primary-or-candidate-keys-in-the-referenced-table)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your table `Autocare` has a **compound** primary key made up from **two columns**:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDAutocar] ASC, [IDTipAutocar] ASC),
```

Therefore, any table that wishes to reference `Autocare` **must also** provide **both columns** in their foreign key!

So this will obviously **not** work:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Autocare] 
   FOREIGN KEY ([IDAutocar]) 
   REFERENCES [Autocare]([IDAutocar])
```

since it references only *one* of the two columns of the primary key of `Autocare`.

You need to add that second column `IDTipAutocar` to your `Curse` table and include it in your foreign key:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Autocare] 
   FOREIGN KEY ([IDAutocar], [IDTipAutocar]) 
   REFERENCES [Autocare]([IDAutocar], [IDTipAutocar])
```

Your foreign keys **must always** reference **the WHOLE** primary key - not just parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key must reference a unique key, be it primary or not. In your current supplied DDL, the unique identifier (primary key) in `Autocare` is the combination of `IDAutocar` and `IDTipAutocar`. On the other hand, you have `Curse` referencing `Autocare.IDAutocar`, which is not unique.

You can either add `IDTipAutocar` to `Curse` (and its foreign key definition):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Curse] (
    [IDCursa] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [IDTraseu] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [Data] TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    [IDCompanie] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [NrLocuri] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [IDAutocar] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL, 
    [IDTipAutocar] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Trasee] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDTraseu]) 
        REFERENCES [Trasee]([IDTraseu]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Companii]
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDCompanie])
        REFERENCES [Companii]([IDCompanie]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Curse_Autocare]
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDAutocar], [IDTipAutocar]) 
        REFERENCES [Autocare]([IDAutocar], [IDTipAutocar])
)
```

Alternatively, you could remove `IDTipAutocar` from `Autocare`'s primary key definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Autocare] 
(
     [IDAutocar]    NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL,
     [IDTipAutocar] NUMERIC (18, 0) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDAutocar] ASC),

     CONSTRAINT [FK_Autogari_TipAutocar] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([IDTipAutocar]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[TipAutocar] ([IDTipAutocar])
);
```

Which ever makes more sense from your business logic's perspective.